# Header & Paragraph texts lead to a page when clicked on

Tags: html

I am creating a small site for my department. My first page is called the "Home" page and it is located inside a file called index.html. In my `body` tag I have a header tag where I welcome the users to the site and a paragraph tag saying what this particuylar site is for. This is the HTML code I have from the title tage to the last `nav` menu I have:

```
 <title>Welcome | Finance Department</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">

        <div id="branding">
        <h1><span class="highlight">Finance and Accounting Portal</span></h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</li>
            <li><a href="accountspayable.html">Accounts Payable</li>
            <li><a href="purchasing.html">Purchasing</li>
            <li><a href="payroll.html">Payroll</li>
            <li><a href="documents.html">Documents</li>
            <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section id="showcase">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to the Finance Department Homepage</h1>
  <p>This is an inter-organizational site where employees can find popular documents pertaining to financials.</p>
</div>
  <img src="./img/hello.jpg">
  </section>

<nav>
  <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</li>
      <li><a href="accountspayable.html">Accounts Payable</li>
      <li><a href="purchasing.html">Purchasing</li>
      <li><a href="payroll.html">Payroll</li>
      <li><a href="documents.html">Documents</li>
      <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

With this as it is now, the welcome to.. header and the This is an inter-organizational... paragraph tags are clickable and when I click them, it takes me to the FAQ page. I just want the header and the paragraph to be plain text, not clickable links.

[image: inspecting header & paragrahg tags in browser]

When I inspect the header and paragraph tags that are causing issues in my browser, I have an additional `<a href="faqs.html">` before my `section id="showcase">`. When I delete that additional tag, the header & paragraph tags are no longer clickable. But, my html does not have that additional `<a href...` tag so I'm confused as to where it came from. Does anyone know if how I can correct this for good?

Comment: You probably have elements overlapping, so that what you _think_ you clicked is not what you _actually_ clicked. Should be easy enough to figure out using browser dev tools, so give those a try - right click on the area in question, “inspect element” (or similar), and see where you land. If you need more help from us on this, then you need to show your CSS, too - preferably the whole thing in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: @CBroe thanks a lot! I'll insect it in my browser and see if I can fix it from there. If not, I'll be happy to post the CSS code in a minimal, complete, and verifiable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not closed Hyperlinks tag in you code.

```
  <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="accountspayable.html">Accounts Payable</a></li>
  <li><a href="purchasing.html">Purchasing</a></li>
  <li><a href="payroll.html">Payroll</a></li>
  <li><a href="documents.html">Documents</a></li>
  <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li>
```

Check your code properly.